# Directing subdomains to other servers

Tags: apache-2.2

I've got a number of web applications running under different instances of Tomcat on my server and I've got one instance of Apache running on port 80.

I to configure the Apache instance so that incoming requests with subdomains will redirect to the appropriate servers.

For example requests to `http://wiki.mydomain.com` should redirect to `http://localhost:8080`

Is this possible by configuring a virtual host?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod_rewrite to do this. There are some examples of rewriting one URL to another URL at the bottom of the module's documentation (none of the examples have non-default ports, but that shouldn't be a problem): https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the [same answer I submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651093/1080668) to another question, but I believe it applies here.  You use the word "redirect" but I really think you mean that you want the public web user to access your localhost:8080 server, which wouldn't work by a simple redirect or URL rewrite.  This is how you would proxy the connection to your localhost:8080 server, along with other extra usage as well if you wanted.

Via `mod_proxy` in Apache2, you can proxy different paths into different destinations at localhost or anywhere else accessible by your server, including within your local network (if your server can access it).

For this you would use `ProxyPass` ([Apache2 Docs for ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), which is *very* useful reading) like the example below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName some.example.host.xyz

  DocumentRoot /var/www/your-document-root

  Alias /clients/ /var/www/clients/
  ProxyPass /clients/ !
  ScriptAlias /something-using-cgi/ /var/www/cgi-stuff/
  ProxyPass /something-using-cgi/ !

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPass /elsewhere/ http://elsewhere.example.host.xyz:1234/
  ProxyPassReverse /elsewhere/ http://elsewhere.example.host.xyz:1234/
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll want to be sure that you set your proxy security such that external users can't use your reverse proxy as a forward proxy, too.  You can do that via `ProxyRequests` as described in the official Apache2 docs.  The way I did this on a server is to put this in your server-wide config (you should verify on your own that this is secure enough):

```
# disables forward proxy
ProxyRequests Off
```